# cesium.js The cone changes with the heading, pitch, and roll of the satellite model, and the vertex position of the cone remains unchanged

Tags: javascript, cesiumjs

I want to use a cone to represent the orthophoto of the satellite model.The cone changes with the heading, pitch, and roll of the satellite model, and the vertex position of the cone remains unchanged.
The effect is similar to http://cesium.marsgis.cn/cesium-example/editor.html#27_space_satellite.

This is a method for finding the cone matrix I wrote according to my needs. When I only change the pitch value, the cone can be drawn correctly, and when the pitch and roll are changed at the same time, the cone vertex changes.
I know it needs to be calculated by the offset, but I don't know how to calculate the correct offset for any scroll value?

```
computedModelMatrix(position,attitude,length){
        //position Represents the latitude, longitude and altitude of the satellite, attitude represents 
        //the heading of the satellite, pitch, roll, length represents the length of the cone
        let oldZ = length/2;
        let oldLongitude=position.longitude;
        let oldLatitude=position.latitude;
        let roll=attitude.roll;
        let pitch=attitude.pitch;
        let headingRadians=Cesium.Math.toRadians(roll);
        let rollRadians=Cesium.Math.toRadians(roll);
        let pitchRadians=Cesium.Math.toRadians(pitch);
        let newLongitude:number,newLatitude:number,newAltitude: number;
        let L=oldZ/Math.cos(rollRadians)/Math.cos(pitchRadians);
        let deg=Math.acos(oldZ/L);
        let distance =oldZ*Math.tan(deg);
        let x=(oldZ*Math.tan(pitch));
        let y=(oldZ*Math.tan(roll));
        let angle;
        if (roll>=0&&pitch>=0){
            //夹角在0-90度
            if (pitch==0&&roll==0){
                angle=0;
            } else if (pitch==0){
                angle=0
            } else if (roll==0){
                angle=90;
            }else{
                angle =Math.atan(x/y);
            }
        }
        else if (pitch>0&&roll<0) {
            angle =Math.atan(y/x)+90;
        }
        else if (pitch<0&&roll<0){
            angle=Math.atan(x/y)+180;
        }
        else{
            angle=Math.atan(y/x)+270;
        }
        newAltitude=oldZ;
        //Find the longitude and latitude of another point by angle and distance
        let resultPisiotion =GetPosition.computerThatLonLat(oldLongitude,oldLatitude,angle,distance);
        newLongitude=resultPisiotion.lon;
        newLatitude=resultPisiotion.lat;
        let centerOnEllipsoid = Cesium.Cartesian3.fromDegrees(newLongitude, newLatitude, newAltitude);
        let hpr = new Cesium.HeadingPitchRoll(headingRadians,pitchRadians, rollRadians);
        let result ={
            modelMatrix:Cesium.Transforms.headingPitchRollToFixedFrame(centerOnEllipsoid, hpr),
            length:2*L
        };
        return result;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
computedModelMatrix(Cartesian3: any, attitude: any, length: any) {
        //锥体距离卫星的高度
        let oldLength = length / 2;
        let centerCartesian3 = new Cesium.Cartesian3(Cartesian3.x, Cartesian3.y, Cartesian3.z);
        let oldX = 0, oldY = 0, oldZ = -oldLength, newX = 0, newY = 0, newZ = 0;
        let heading = attitude.heading;
        //规定顺时针为正旋转,正东方向为0度
        if (heading < 0) {
            heading = heading + 360;
        }
        let roll = attitude.roll;
        let pitch = attitude.pitch;
        let headingRadians = Cesium.Math.toRadians(heading);
        let pitchRadians = Cesium.Math.toRadians(pitch);
        let rollRadians = Cesium.Math.toRadians(roll);
        let hpr = new Cesium.HeadingPitchRoll(headingRadians, pitchRadians, rollRadians);
        let orientation = Cesium.Transforms.headingPitchRollQuaternion(centerCartesian3, hpr);
        //旋转roll
        newY = oldY + oldLength * Math.sin(rollRadians);
        newZ = oldZ + oldLength - oldLength * Math.cos(rollRadians);
        let pitchTouying = oldLength * Math.cos(rollRadians);//进行pitch变化时在Y轴和Z轴组成的平面的投影
        //旋转pitch
        newX = oldX + pitchTouying * Math.sin(pitchRadians);
        newZ = newZ + (pitchTouying - pitchTouying * Math.cos(pitchRadians));
        if (heading != 0) {
            let headingTouying = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(Math.abs(newX), 2) + Math.pow(Math.abs(newY), 2));//进行heading变化时在Y轴和X轴组成的平面的投影
            //旋转heading
            let Xdeg = Cesium.Math.toDegrees(Math.acos(Math.abs(newX) / Math.abs(headingTouying)));//现有投影线与X轴的夹角
            let newXdeg = 0;//旋转heading后与X轴的夹角
            let newXRadians = 0;//旋转heading后与X轴的夹角弧度
            if (newX >= 0 && newY >= 0) {
                newXdeg = heading - Xdeg;
            } else if (newX > 0 && newY < 0) {
                newXdeg = heading + Xdeg;
            } else if (newX < 0 && newY > 0) {
                newXdeg = heading + (180 + Xdeg);
            } else {
                newXdeg = heading + (180 - Xdeg)
            }
            if (newXdeg >= 360) {
                newXdeg = 360 - newXdeg;
            }
            if (newXdeg >= 0 && newXdeg <= 90) {
                newXRadians = Cesium.Math.toRadians(newXdeg);
                newY = -headingTouying * Math.sin(newXRadians);
                newX = headingTouying * Math.cos(newXRadians);
            } else if (newXdeg > 90 && newXdeg <= 180) {
                newXRadians = Cesium.Math.toRadians(180 - newXdeg);
                newY = -headingTouying * Math.sin(newXRadians);
                newX = -headingTouying * Math.cos(newXRadians)
            } else if (newXdeg > 180 && newXdeg <= 270) {
                newXRadians = Cesium.Math.toRadians(newXdeg - 180);
                newY = headingTouying * Math.sin(newXRadians);
                newX = -(headingTouying * Math.cos(newXRadians))
            } else {
                newXRadians = Cesium.Math.toRadians(360 - newXdeg);
                newY = headingTouying * Math.sin(newXRadians);
                newX = headingTouying * Math.cos(newXRadians)
            }
        }
        let offset = new Cesium.Cartesian3(newX, newY, newZ);
        let newPosition = this.computeOffset(centerCartesian3, offset);
        return Cesium.Matrix4.fromTranslationQuaternionRotationScale(newPosition, orientation, new Cesium.Cartesian3(1, 1, 1))
    }
computeOffset(Cartesian3: any, offset: any) {
        let enuTransform = Cesium.Transforms.eastNorthUpToFixedFrame(Cartesian3);
        Cesium.Matrix4.multiplyByPointAsVector(enuTransform, offset, offset);
        return Cesium.Cartesian3.add(Cartesian3, offset, new Cesium.Cartesian3());
    }
```